# Alembic Migrations on Multiple Models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am attempting to create a revision with `--autogenerate` using Alembic for two Models, but am receiving a duplicate table keys error. Does, a schema need to be specified?  If so, how can it be set?  The documentation I've read says to use `__table_args__ = {'schema': 'somename'}`, but that hasn't helped.  Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

My current setup is:

**base.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

**workspace.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from base import Base

class WorkspaceModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'workspaces'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

**host.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from base import Base

class HostModel(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'hosts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=true)
    ip = Column(String)
```

**alembic/env.py**

```
from host import HostModel
from workspace import WorkspaceModel
target_metadata = [HostModel.metadata, WorkspaceModel.metadata]
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: Duplicate table keys across multiple MetaData objects: "hosts", "workspaces"
```

Comment: `target_metadata` should just be `target_metadata = Base.metadata`.

Comment: Thanks @univerio. When I tried doing that, the model data wasn't read and gave me a blank migration; upgrade() and downgrade() didn't contain anything.

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't just mean it thinks your schema has no changes?

Comment: I am sure.  The alembic/versions directory contents were deleted, and the database was dropped and recreated.  Switching to ```target_metadata = Base.metadata``` generated blank migrations.

Comment: Then are you sure you've imported everything correctly? Using `Base.metadata` doesn't mean you can remove the imports `from host import HostModel` and `from workspace import WorkspaceModel`.

Comment: Oh wow, wasn't importing the models.  That solved the issue.  I'd be happy to accept if you post as an answer.  Certainly appreciate the help.

Comment: Unfortunately, importing models in alembic 1.5.4 didn't help: upgrade(), downgrade() were left unpopulated

Comment: If you are using flask-sqlalchemy the equivalent of `Base.metadata` is `db.Model.metadata`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To make it clear from what [@esdotzed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60388520/641451) and [@univerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053955/alembic-migrations-on-multiple-models#comment83106201_48053955) said, you have to use a single `Base.metadata` - but **still `import` the individual models**.

In the original question, this is how the `alembic/env.py` should look like:

```py
from base import Base

# This two won't be referenced, but *have* to be imported to populate `Base.metadata`
from host import HostModel
from workspace import WorkspaceModel

target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

If you didn't `import` both models, the autogenerated migration would end up deleting your whole database - because `Base.metadata` doesn't know about any model by itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, importing models in alembic 1.5.4 didn't help: upgrade(), downgrade() were left unpopulated

Comment: I hope this answer gets accepted because it's the correct one

Comment: Another thing you should note: If you're trying to create the fist migration, the database you're connecting with **must be empty**. You may connect to a temp db to generate the migration and then switch back.

Comment: If you have configured precommit hooks in git, it will remove these unused imports any work around for this?

Comment: Yes this works, i come to here after the error ValueError: Duplicate table keys across multiple MetaData objects.

This answer solve the autogenerate detect blank tables problem for multiple model scenario.

Answer (score 2):

quoting univerio's answer from the comment section:

`target_metadata` should just be `target_metadata = Base.metadata`

Using Base.metadata doesn't mean you can remove the imports from host import HostModel and from workspace import WorkspaceModel

It worked for me.

Comment: @snakecharmerb this user just moved an answer provided in the comment section into an actual answer. Which i think is a valid thing to do.

Comment: @Ente ah, the "answer" fooled me.  Good edit.  I can't retract the NAA flag, but I acknowledge that this answer should be left open.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to @mgarciaisaia answer, it will work but the thing is when I tried changing, for example, the max length of **username** field of **User** model and running `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "test migration"`, alembic output a migration file with empty `upgrade()` and `downgrade()` functions!

**Note: the following operations will erase your data from the database so please back them up beforehand!**

In order to update the changes made to the original **User** model, I had to

1. Delete the first migration file
2. Rerun `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "update user model"` and `alembic upgrade head` again for the changes to appear inside `upgrade()` and `downgrade()` functions of the migration file.