# Python SQLAlchemy Alembic Migrations on Multiple Models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, database-migration, alembic

I have checked out [Alembic Migrations on Multiple Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053955/alembic-migrations-on-multiple-models) but the I way I build my SQLAlchemy models is different.

In `src/models/__init__.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
from .Model1 import Model1
MyMetadata = [Model1.metadata]
```

In `src/models/Model1.py`:

```
from . import db
class Model1(db.Model):
```

In `migrations/env.py`:

```
from src.models import MyMetadata
target_metadata = MyMetadata
```

When I run `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Initial"`, I bump into the following error:

```
ValueError: Duplicate table keys across multiple MetaData objects: "model1", "model2", "model3"
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: You want `MyMetadata = db.Model.metadata`; `db.Model` is equivalent to `Base` in flask-sqlalchemy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alembic Migrations on Multiple Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053955/alembic-migrations-on-multiple-models)