# alembic autogenerate revision try to drop all the index and tables of my database

Tags: database, migration, fastapi, alembic

I'm working on an existant FastAPI application which uses a GCP SQL database. I made minor changes locally on the database schema and I created a local postgresql database to test my changes. I autogenerated migration with alembic , But it generates a weired changes which intend to drop index and tables of my database. I'm sure that I'm missing an important step, can anyone experienced with alembic could help me out to get unstuck.

```
"""user_namesapace_revision

def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_index('ix_delegate_approver_email', table_name='delegate')
    op.drop_index('ix_delegate_delegate_email', table_name='delegate')
    op.drop_index('ix_delegate_end_date', table_name='delegate')
    op.drop_index('ix_delegate_id', table_name='delegate')
    op.drop_index('ix_delegate_start_date', table_name='delegate')
    op.drop_table('delegate')
    op.drop_table('workflow_namespaces')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_workflow_approvers_id', table_name='request_workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_workflow_created_at', table_name='request_workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_workflow_end_process', table_name='request_workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_workflow_id', table_name='request_workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_workflow_position', table_name='request_workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_workflow_sous_position', table_name='request_workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_workflow_status', table_name='request_workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_workflow_updated_at', table_name='request_workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_workflow_workflow_step_id', table_name='request_workflow')
    op.drop_table('request_workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_active_namespace', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_created_at', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_email', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_first_name', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_id', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_language', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_last_name', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_line_manager', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_namespace', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_password', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_role', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_token', table_name='users')
    op.drop_index('ix_users_updated_at', table_name='users')
    op.drop_table('users')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_condition_approver_id', table_name='workflow_condition')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_condition_criteria', table_name='workflow_condition')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_condition_end_process', table_name='workflow_condition')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_condition_id', table_name='workflow_condition')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_condition_operator', table_name='workflow_condition')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_condition_reviewerField', table_name='workflow_condition')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_condition_type', table_name='workflow_condition')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_condition_value', table_name='workflow_condition')
    op.drop_table('workflow_condition')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_created_at', table_name='request')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_current_step_position', table_name='request')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_dataObj', table_name='request')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_editUrl', table_name='request')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_element_id', table_name='request')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_loop', table_name='request')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_request_id', table_name='request')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_status', table_name='request')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_timeZone', table_name='request')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_updated_at', table_name='request')
    op.drop_table('request')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_actions_action', table_name='request_actions')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_actions_approvers_id', table_name='request_actions')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_actions_comment', table_name='request_actions')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_actions_created_at', table_name='request_actions')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_actions_id', table_name='request_actions')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_actions_loop', table_name='request_actions')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_actions_request_workflow_id', table_name='request_actions')
    op.drop_index('ix_request_actions_workflow_id', table_name='request_actions')
    op.drop_table('request_actions')
    op.drop_table('users_namespaces')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_created_at', table_name='workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_id_template', table_name='workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_id_workflow', table_name='workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_name', table_name='workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_status', table_name='workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_storeResponses', table_name='workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_type', table_name='workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_url', table_name='workflow')
    op.drop_table('workflow')
    op.drop_index('ix_namespace_billingEmail', table_name='namespace')
    op.drop_index('ix_namespace_created_at', table_name='namespace')
    op.drop_index('ix_namespace_id', table_name='namespace')
    op.drop_index('ix_namespace_name', table_name='namespace')
    op.drop_index('ix_namespace_owner_id', table_name='namespace')
    op.drop_index('ix_namespace_plan', table_name='namespace')
    op.drop_index('ix_namespace_quota', table_name='namespace')
    op.drop_index('ix_namespace_status', table_name='namespace')
    op.drop_index('ix_namespace_updated_at', table_name='namespace')
    op.drop_index('ix_namespace_usedQuota', table_name='namespace')
    op.drop_table('namespace')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_ccEmails', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_ccType', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_column', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_config_id', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_emailLanguage', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_finalApproval', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_formAccess', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_onHold', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_sendBack', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_sheetId', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_sheetName', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_template', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_triggerOwner', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_triggerStatus', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_validationReminder', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_addon_config_validationReminderTime', table_name='addon_config')
    op.drop_table('addon_config')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_steps_id', table_name='workflow_steps')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_steps_name', table_name='workflow_steps')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_steps_parent_id', table_name='workflow_steps')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_steps_position', table_name='workflow_steps')
    op.drop_index('ix_workflow_steps_sous_position', table_name='workflow_steps')
    op.drop_table('workflow_steps')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have made a mistake in alembic's `env.py` file. If you use `autogenerate`, you should import all your models.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053955/alembic-migrations-on-multiple-models).